# Need illustrated advice on Socket P/Merom BSEL mod

Tags: laptop, cpu, overclocking, intel-core2, processor-socket

I have got [Intel T2370](http://ark.intel.com/products/34445/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T2370-1M-Cache-1_73-GHz-533-MHz-FSB)(133FSB/Socket P/Merom) CPU and [ASUS F5SL](http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-f5sl-ap018c-15-4-core-2-duo-t5450-vista-home-premium-2-gb-ram-160-gb-hdd/specs/)(SIS chipset) laptop.

I see those as perfect candidates for BSEL pinmod yet I can't find detailed sure description on how to do it. There is a post on Notebook review titled BSEL “[Mod on a socket P explained with photos](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/390696-bsel-mod-socket-p-explained-photos.html)” yet photos has gone astray.

So maybe someone has those photos saved (or any other that detail what pins to short to set FSB to 166 or to 200?)

P.S. Please restrain yourself from commenting on merits of overclocking laptop CPU guys.)